# Java Memory/Number of Entries Limit?

Tags: java, list, memory, max

I am working on a program in Java, that has the purpose to parse it in specific ways.

At one point i need to add certain Values depending on an alorithem over the last n (e.g.) rows:

```
private void eFSF(PFCC pfCC, csvReader reader) {
        List<List<String>> fileDataList;
        reader.changeModulo(1);
        fileDataList = reader.parseToList();
        HashMap<Long, List<String>> hashedList = new HashMap<>();

        long rowCnt = 0L;
        for (List<String> list : fileDataList) {
            hashedList.put(rowCnt, list);
            rowCnt++;
        }

        AWI wI = getWI(pfChainContext, fileDataList);
        hashedList.get(0L).add(setFeatureHeader());

        //iterate over without header
        long iterCnt = 1L;
        long moduloCnt = 0L;
        LinkedList<Long> lastLines = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Long line : hashedList.keySet()) {
            if (line == 0L)
                continue;

            // check measure start, first measurement
            if (hashedList.get(line).get(1).equals("0")) {
                moduloCnt = 0L;
            }

            if( moduloCnt % pfChainContext.getEsize() == 0 || pfChainContext.size() == 1){
                if (lastLines.size() != 0) { //prob first line
                    moduloTrigger(hashedList, wIter, lastLines);

                    //clean Data
                    lastLines.clear();
                    wIter.clear();
                }
            }

            wIter.addLine(hashedList.get(line));
            lastLines.add(iterCnt);
            moduloCnt++;
            iterCnt++;
        }

        // if some "hangover" lines exist:
        if (lastLines.size() != 0) {
            moduloTrigger(hashedList, wIter, lastLines);
        }

        //write File Back
        ...
    }

private void moduloTrigger(HashMap<Long, List<String>> fileDataList, AWI wIter, LinkedList<Long> lastLines) {
    fileDataList.get(lastLines.getFirst()).add((String)wIter.getDFCW());

    //fill with zeros
    for (Long i : lastLines.subList(1, lastLines.size()))
        fileDataList.get(i).add("0");
}
```

In general the algorithem works fine. But i encounter the following Problem:
After the ~65536th Line some of the Data is wrong by one step.

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with variable Limits, but changing the number to Long did not change the situation.
After Debuging the Code i found out, that the Problem already exists in the Datastructure, so it has nothing to do with writing the Data back.

I am working on a 64-bit Machine with 64-bit Java.

**Does anyone have an Idea why he keeps messing with the lines?**

Answer (score 1):

65536 is the smallest value that can't be represented as a Java `char`.  All other types have either smaller limits (127 for `byte`, 32767 for `short`) or significantly larger.

- `byte` is 8b signed
- `short` is 16b signed
- `char` is 16b unsigned
- `int` is 32b signed
- `long` is 64b signed
- `float` is 32b signed floating, so 23b mantissa
- `double` is 64b signed floating, so 52b mantissa

> but changing the number to Float

Changing an integral type to `Float` won't get you as much as changing it to a larger integral type.

> I am working on a 64-bit Machine with 64-bit Java.

This affects the amount of addressable memory and the amount of memory consumed by object references, but not the bit-width of numeric primitives in Java.

Comment: Sry i meant long instead of float. What are the limits of lists? Could this also be a possible error?

Comment: @NicolasAntor: *"Could this be a possible error?"* ... The Java platform has been continuously developed, tested, and optimized for over 15 years.  It is extremely unlikely that the problem you are having is due to idiosyncratic or erroneous behavior in the language.

Comment: You probably did not understand my question. Of course i am not blaming the JVM for any Problems. But the Specification might just limit the size of Lists an other data structures, just the way they limit numbers.

Comment: @NicolasAntor, List and string indices are 32b signed ints, so the limit is about 2billion-ish.

Comment: Small out of bounds access of large lists will cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since (`Integer.MAX_VALUE + smallPositiveValue`) will underflow and be negative and the list implementations in the core libraries do bounds checks.